# Change value storyboard from AppDelegate

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a `imageView` in my storyboard. Now I want to set `imageView` to nil when the app will enter the background (`applicationDidEnterBackground` and `applicationWillTerminate`). But I couldn't find a good way to do this.

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    .... imageView.image = nil; ?
}
```

What is a good way to change a value of imageView from AppDelegate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding this in `viewDidLoad` of my viewcontroller.m file:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(removeImage)
                                             name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification
                                           object:nil];
```

And the removeImage function:

```
- (void) removeImage {
    ImageView.image = nil;
}
```